# finding two sides of a cuboid while knowing the volume

Tags: algebra-precalculus, volume

The volume of a cuboid is $150\,\mathrm m^3$, one side is $2,5\,\mathrm m$, one side is completely unknown ($x$) and the other one is $4$ meters longer ($x+4$). I guessed the sides one being $6$ and the other $10$ but I need to figure it out with a formula.

Comment: Do you know a formula for the volume of a cuboid? If so, set up an equation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the volume formula for this cuboid you get $150=2.5x(x+4)$, and you can divide by $2.5$ to get $x(x+4)=60$, which rearranges to a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0):

The formula for volume is
$$V = lwh$$
where $l$ is the length, $w$ is the width, and $h$ is the height.

You are given:
$$V = 150$$
$$w = 2.5$$
$$l = x$$
$$h = x + 4.$$

Plugging the values into the formula for volume of a cuboid, you get
$$150 = 2.5x(x+4)$$
$$300 = 5x^2 + 20x$$
$$60 = x^2 + 4x$$
$$x^2 + 4x - 60 = 0.$$

Now, this last equation is a *quadratic* in $x$, which can be solved by factoring:
$$(x + 10)(x - 6) = 0.$$
$$x + 10 = 0 \text{ or } x - 6 = 0$$
$$x = -10 \text{ or } x = 6.$$

The root $x = -10$ is extraneous.  Therefore, $x = 6$ and $x + 4 = 10$.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I don't understand how you got from x2+4x−60=0 to (x+10)(x−6)=0 ?

Comment: @user448891, well if you expand $(x + 10)(x - 6)$ using FOIL, what do you get?

Comment: so you did x·x + x·6 + 10·x + 10·6 ? sorry for bothering you I'm just trying to understand because we didn't learn FOIL method yet. (I just googled what it means)

Comment: So you have
$$(x + 10)(x - 6) = x(x - 6) + 10(x - 6) = x^2 - 6x + 10x - 60 = x^2 + 4x - 60.$$
What does this mean?